# Create properties in JSON Object in Loop or otherwise dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array of objects like below as expected by dojo store

```
[
    { "Column 1": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", ... },
    { "Column 1": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", ... },
    { "Column 1": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", ... },
    ...
]
```

The array part is simple, but how do I dynamically create the object keys part? "Column 1" etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to give an idea,

You can access an object attribute using associative array subscript like this:

```
var a = {}
a["col 1"] = "some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArr = [
  { "Column 1": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", ... },
  { "Column 1": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", ... },
  { "Column 1": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", "Column 2": "Value ...", ... },
]

var obj = {};
    obj['your_key'] = 'some value';
    obj['your_another_key'] = 'some other value';
    ...

myArr.push(obj);
```